# Windows Start command handles EXE and BAT differently, the latter is flawed

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, double-quotes

Please how can I run batch file with arguments enclosed in double quotes using the Start command?

If you use EXE file, it works (`calc` is just an example you can test with):

```
start "Some Title" "calc.exe" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"
```

The same syntax calling batch file does not: (in the above, only the extension was replaced)

```
start "Some Title" "calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"
```

Error:

> 'calc.bat"  "arg1" "arg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

(The content of `calc.bat` file does not matter, it can even have zero length.)

**How I can achieve launching `calc.bat` using `start` command** (asynchronously, in separate window) **with arguments `arg1`, `arg 2` and `arg  3`?**

Of course, if you specify arguments without quotes, it works:

```
start "Some Title" "calc.bat" arg1 arg2 arg3
```

---

EDIT:

I actually need `start_all.bat` which starts 3 parallel processes in 3 new windows:

```
set user="abc"
start "Run 1" "calc.bat" "%user%" "arg 1" "arg 2" "arg 3"
start "Run 2" "calc.bat" "%user%" "arg 4" "arg 5" "arg 6"
start "Run 3" "calc.bat" "%user%" "arg 7" "arg 8" "arg 9"
```

but this works only with EXE, not with BAT.

`calc.bat` can be something simple like

```
@echo 1: `%1`
@echo 2: `%2`
@echo 3: `%3`
@pause
```

**Additional question: What if the path with the space is present?**

```bat
set user="abc"
start "Run 1" "c:\batch files\calc.bat" "%user%" "arg 1" "arg 2" "arg 3"
start "Run 2" "c:\batch files\calc.bat" "%user%" "arg 4" "arg 5" "arg 6"
start "Run 3" "c:\batch files\calc.bat" "%user%" "arg 7" "arg 8" "arg 9"
```

Comment: how about `start "Some Title" calc.bat "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"` Can I ask what the purpose of this is? If calling it without the quotes does work, why do you want to call it with quotes?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, some of my arguments can contain spaces: `arg 2` and `arg  3`. Did the command you wrote in your comment work for you?

Comment: it will work yes if you call your arguments correctly in your batch file. what is the content your your `calc.bat` file? is it `%1 %2` etc?

Comment: Yes, I need `%1`, `%2`, `%3` in `calc.bat` file which opens in new window as async process (therefore the `start` command).

Comment: ok, I will post an answer.

Comment: try the answer and let me know.

Comment: Try `start "Some Title" cmd /C "calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"`

Comment: @Aacini running start already calls cmd, so you're calling cmd and cmd /c. have a look at my answer below, it will make sense. :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: The difference is in the way the command-line is parsed. In this way, the OP's problem should be solved...

Comment: @Aacini, but it does not work, that is why I am telling you it is wrong. `start "Some Title" cmd /C ^""D:\Test Folder\calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"^"` will work here, but purely because you are telling start to start cmd /C and then you have to escape the double quotes because you are sending the commands through a series of cmd's the correct method is still to do `start "title" D/ "path" batch "arg" "arg2" "arg 3"`

Answer (score 3):

When using `start` to call a batch file, it actually invokes `cmd /K` implicitly to run the batch file:

```cmd
start "Some Title" cmd /K "calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"
```

The `cmd /K` part consumes the leading and trailing quotation marks, leaving the invalid command line:

```cmd
calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3
```

To compensate for that, provide an additional surrounding pair of quotes; escape them to let the arguments appear quoted to the hosting `cmd` instance too.

```cmd
start "Some Title" ^""calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"^"
```

However, these nested quotation marks most probably confuses the `start` command, so it does no longer recognise the (path to the) batch file that you are trying to call. To avoid that, you must explicitly specify the `cmd /K` part:

```cmd
start "Some Title" cmd /K ^""calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"^"
```

Or, with the full path to the batch file provided:

```cmd
start "Some Title" cmd /K ^""C:\Batch Files\calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"^"
```

Comment: Though I get what you are trying to do, this will not work. I am amazed that the answer actually got upvoted when it does not work.

Comment: @aschipfl Did you test this? it does not work. Like I said, it will try and pass the entire string `calc arg1 arg2 arg 3` as the command. and you will get error stating `Windows cannot find 'calc.bat arg1 arg2 arg3' make sure.....`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, I verified it on my Windows 10 machine (except for the part with the path including spaces as I mentioned); I don't get what should be wrong; anyway, let me check again when I have a chance (I'm on mobile now)...

Comment: it is impossible. it will try and send the entire string as the command. Please show me the content of your batch file you tested with so I can test it as well. Thanks a mill.

Comment: you are already sending calc.bat to the new cmd window. It will except this command with start. Once you add quotes around that and the rest of the string, it assumes that the string in quotes should be the command. so it MUST be without quotes, unless you escale the quotes, but that defeats the purpose of putting them there in the first place. even with path, you need to use `start /D "c:\path to file" calc.bat` else it will fail. using start with batch files is not really a good idea as it causes issues, but if you have to, then there is only one way. :)

Comment: OK, so do we have a solution here for cases which include path to batch file?  E.g.  `c:\batch files\calc.bat`

Comment: no you don't this will never work, unless you call cmd from start, but even though it will work, it is wrong. This answer however will not work.. I will add the other method to my answer, though it is wrong, I still will. but I have given the solution which you seem to not want to accept.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, I finally have found a reliable solution; it seems I have tested originally having stated `cmd /K` explicitly, unintentionally; it appears logical that `start` fails if it cannot see the path to the batch file, so it does not call `cmd /K` then; if you specify `cmd /K` explicitly, `start` does no longer have to resolve the ("over-quoted") path of the batch file as this is nothing but an argument for `cmd /K`. Anyway, I like your work-around using `start /D`, but note that it does not help when the batch file has got a space in its name...

Comment: Thanks for the response. well, yes I only mentioned the solution because you said you must call `start`. It is also not a very good idea to call a batch file 2 words, so you might need to rather consider using underscore or one word names.

Comment: Although I dislike white-spaces in file names too, they are allowed in Windows and so we have to deal with it. Also note that `start` with and without the `/D` option are not equivalent (though I never said using `/D` is incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

you can surely call the batch like this

```
start "Title" calc.bat "arg1" "arg 2"
```

The problem is more with your batch. Let's say you are using ping.exe in the batch. Instead of doing:

```
ping %1 %2 %3
```

You should do:

```
ping %~1 %~2 %~3
```

this will catch the entire args even in quotes.

so if you then do:

```
start ping.bat "127.0.0.1" "-n 6" "-a"
```

it will work

**EDIT**
calc.bat should then be:

```
@echo 1: %~1
@echo 2: %~2
@echo 3: %~3
@pause
```

Which in the example of `ping.bat` would do exactly this:

```
1: 127.0.0.1
2: -n 1
3: -a
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Finaly, if you take what you mentioned in a comment to launch batch 3 times, with different paramaters for each. You would then have the content of `calc.bat` as this

```
ping %~1 %~2 %~3
ping %~4 %~5 %~6
ping %~7 %~8 %~9
```

then you will do call it like this.

```
start calc.exe "127.0.0.1% "-n 6" "-a" "192.0.1.2" "-n 2" "-a" "128.0.9.1% "-n 1" "-a"
```

**LAST EDIT**

If you must call start with path you need to call like this:

```
start "title" /D "c:\batch files" calc.bat "arg1" "arg2" "arg 3"
```

So after a lot of discussion and not everyone seeming to understand how start works when commands to other files, and being persistent that /D is incorrect, here is another, yet incorrect, solution.

```
start "Some Title" cmd /K ^""C:\Batch Files\calc.bat" "arg1" "arg 2" "arg  3"^"
```

Note, can be used with /C as well or just cmd. K will purely keep the window open.

This is more or less what was referred to in the other answer, but note you are calling cmd /K. Though this will work, it is wrong, you are calling cmd with start which in fact is also by default calling cmd. This defeats the purpose of use start either way. If start was used purely to send the title, this could have been done in the batch file already and you could have just called the batch without path.

Comment: then this will work. Just try it. Make sure you write your batch correctly. make sure you use `%~1` `%~2` ... `%~9` in your batch

Comment: if you want me to make it even easier, post your batch code in your question and I can show you

Comment: This actually *works* (thank you!) only until I put batch name into quotes. So if I change batch name into `"calc bat"` or `"C:\batch files\calc bat"`, this has errors. Could you resolve them? (See the updated question) You already helped me, so +1.

Comment: I see. What a workaround. (Change current dir instead of specifying path to batch file.) I'll wait until @aschipfl checks his solution and then I will decide.

Comment: it is not changing current dir. that is correct wat to specify dir for start. do start /? for help

Comment: I know, it is not changing current dir for caller, but for commands inside BAT file. Typically, commands inside BAT file retain directory of caller context. Not here. This is why I called it a workaround.

Comment: still not a work around. understand how start works and double quotes when calling batch. you will then see :)

Comment: in other words. if you must use start to call a batch with args. this is the way

Comment: _I know, it is not changing current dir for caller, but for commands inside BAT file_ that is not correct. /D is purely calling the path to the calc.bat file

Comment: I tested that under Windows 10 and I see that if `/D` is used, the path is changed to given folder for batch called from `start` command. This is also confirmed in help displayed by command `start /?`.

Comment: @miroxlav That is exactly the idea. You want to open the calc.bat file in a location other than your path where you are running the command from. If you are in C:\ and run `start "title" /D "c:\batch files\" calc.bat ...` it calls the file in the path because you are specifying the path. it is exactly the same as doing `"C:\batch files\calc.bat"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try invoking the standard interpreter and escape the quotation marks like this:

`start "Some Title" "%COMSPEC%" /c"calc.bat ^"arg1^" ^"arg 2^" ^"arg  3^""`

Comment: Good. This works until I use path to bath file, then it has similar problem as [aschipfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44437110/2392157). I used `start "Some Title" "%COMSPEC%" /c"^"C:\batch files\calc.bat^" ^"arg1^" ^"arg 2^" ^"arg  3^""`.